# How can i see the definer of a table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am currently trying to make a dump of my production database and deploy it in my development database.

Before i do so, i am willing to add a script that will change the definer of the database's tables to a definer that is used in my development database after the deployment is complete.

Is there a way to tell what is the current definer for a table?
Iv'e tried `SHOW CREATE TABLE` but it doesn't give me the definer of that table.

Note that i already have a script that does so for another schema, but i am not sure if the definer for the other schema is the same.

Also, i couldn't find an answer to this over the internet, so i am asking this here.

Thanks.

Comment: I think only views and stored procedures have "definers".

Answer (score 1):

Databases and tables do not have a 'definer' (or `DBO`) in MySQL.

"users" are "GRANTed" permissions to access databases and/or tables.  Will having different `GRANTs` solve whatever you are trying to solve?

A related topic...  Stored Routines execute as the "invoker" or a specified "user" (your choice when creating the routine), but I don't think that is what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You, or others lead to this question, may be thinking of procedures/functions/triggers/events/views that may be correlated with the tables you're attempting to find definers for.

[Stored Object Access Control](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-objects-security.html)

> Stored programs (procedures, functions, triggers, and events) and views are defined prior to use and, when referenced, execute within a security context that determines their privileges. The privileges applicable to execution of a stored object are controlled by its DEFINER attribute and SQL SECURITY characteristic.

In which case, you may find the following queries helpful:

- [`SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-procedure.html)
- [`SHOW CREATE FUNCTION func_name`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-function.html)
- [`SHOW TRIGGERS FROM db_name`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-triggers.html)
- [`SHOW CREATE EVENT event_name`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-event.html)
- [`SHOW CREATE VIEW view_name`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-view.html)